# Setting the range for the x axis value for different time values - Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly

Even when the range is set to a specific time value, all the time values are getting displayed on the graph. The code snippet is available below.

```
import datetime as dt
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd # dataframe/matrix library
from pandas_summary import DataFrameSummary # nice summaries for pandas dataframes
import numpy as np # matrix math 
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot # interactive charts
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
x = 10;
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=48, freq='H')
time = rng.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date1': rng, 'Val': x*np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df.set_index('Val')
df['time'] = df['Date1'].dt.time
df['date'] = df['Date1'].dt.date
startTime = df.iloc[5]['time']
endTime = df.iloc[10]['time']
data = [
go.Scatter(
    x=df[df['date'] == date]['time'], 
    y=df[df['date'] == date]['Val'],
    name=str(date)
)for date in  df.date.unique()]
Layout = go.Layout(title="Test VS Time",xaxis=dict(title='Time',range=[startTime,endTime]),yaxis=dict(title='Value'));
df.iplot(layout=Layout.to_plotly_json(),data=data)
```

The following images show the output graph and the data frame.

[Plotly graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0t40.jpg)

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4MEF.jpg)

Comment: Could you share a piece of the dataframe? It is hard to tell if we can't reproduce the experiment.

Comment: Hi vlizana I have updated the question with a view of the data frame. Please let me know if this image is sufficient.

Comment: "It is hard to tell if we can't reproduce the experiment" -- now we theoretically can reproduce, but would have to type everything again, while reading from a small image. Can't you just post the raw data?

Comment: Hi all. I have updated the question by refining the content and added a sample code snippet.